# How to know process of job

Tags: java, process

I have a timer code

```
public void pollPnlFilesFromArgon(final String dirLocation) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {     
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
                if(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)>22 && c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)>=55){
                        this.cancel();                          
                }
                List<String> filesPaths= new ArrayList<String>();
                File folder= new File(dirLocation);
                File[] listOfFiles= folder.listFiles();
                for (File file : listOfFiles) {                 
                    if((file.getName().startsWith("DAILY")||file.getName().startsWith("MONTHLY_Europe")) && file.getName().endsWith(".csv")){
                        filesPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());                     
                    }else{
                        if(file.isFile()){
                        File orig=createOrigDir(dirLocation);
                         file.renameTo(new File(orig.getAbsoluteFile()+"/"+file.getName().substring(0,file.getName().length()-4)+"-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".csv"));
                    }
                    }
                }               
                if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(filesPaths)){
                    try {
                        updateBalancePnlFromArgon(filesPaths,dirLocation);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.error(e);
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }, 0, 60000);
```

This is supposed to start at 12 at midnight and end at 11:55 at night. If i want to kill the process in between i am not able to do it in unix. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

unix.stackexchange provides you the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110911/how-to-get-the-job-id) to finding a job's process id and how to terminate that process.